# Cast the return type of a lambda expression and sort a list with a custom comparator

Tags: lambda, casting, java-8, method-reference

I have a [`List<DefaultMutableTreeNode>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html) and want to sort the list by a property of the [`userObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html#getUserObject--) with a custom comparator.

In order to provide a simple example I will use the user object `Person`

```
public class Person {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    public Person(String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

}
```

and a custom comparator

```
public class PersonComparator implements Comparator<Person> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        // to keep the example simple I just compare the firstnames here
        return o1.getFirstname().compareTo(o2.getFirstname());
    }

}
```

My first thought was to use `Comparator.comparing` with a method reference as key extractor and a key comparator.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<DefaultMutableTreeNode> nodes = new ArrayList<DefaultMutableTreeNode>();

    nodes.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new Person("James", "Smith")));
    nodes.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new Person("Paul", "Clark")));
    nodes.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new Person("Anthony", "Brown")));

    Comparator<Person> myComparator = new PersonComparator();
    nodes.sort(Comparator.comparing(DefaultMutableTreeNode::getUserObject, myComparator));

}
```

But this gives me (of course) a compiler error since the `DefaultMutableTreeNode.getUserObject()` returns an `Object` and not a `Person`.

How can I cast the retrun type of the lambda method reference `DefaultMutableTreeNode::getUserObject`?

Or do you have any other options?

**EDIT:**

I can do it this way, but is there an easier way? (in one line)

```
Function<DefaultMutableTreeNode, Object> userObject = DefaultMutableTreeNode::getUserObject;
nodes.sort(Comparator.comparing(userObject.andThen(Person.class::cast), myComparator));
```

Comment: `nodes.sort(comparing(t -> ((Person)t.getUserObject()).getFirstname()));` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question talks about "lambda method reference" but this doesn't exist: there are [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), and there are [method-references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). A method-reference is a special feature where, instead of writing a lambda expression that would simply invoke another existing method, you use the `::` operator to refer to that method directly by name.

But in this case, since `getUserObject` returns an `Object` and not a `Person`, you won't be able to directly use a method-reference here: you need to have more code than simply refering to `getUserObject`: a cast is needed.

As such, use a lambda expression:

```
nodes.sort(Comparator.comparing(t -> (Person) t.getUserObject(), myComparator));
```

Another way would be to create a method that returns a `Person` instead of an `Object`, and refer to that method:

```
private static Person getPerson(DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
    return (Person) node.getUserObject();
}

// assuming "getPerson" in a class called MyClass
nodes.sort(Comparator.comparing(MyClass::getPerson, myComparator));
```

---

Note that the `PersonComparator` can be written more simply with

```
Comparator<Person> myComparator = Comparator.comparing(Person::getFirstname);
```

Comment: The `PersonComparator` is just for the example. My real comparator and user object and the comparison logic is more complex. Thus I use custom comparator.

Comment: Of course, for this simple case, you can combine them directly: `nodes.sort( Comparator.comparing( t -> ((Person)t.getUserObject()).getFirstname()) );`

Comment: @René Link: if your custom comparator contains a logic more complex than what `Comparator.comparing(X::oneProperty).thenComparing(X::nextProperty)` etc. offers, you should rethink your design. Perhaps, the more complicated logic is actually tied to a property type and should be split off from the `Person` comparator, like with `Comparator.comparing(Person::getFirstname, Collator.getInstance())`…